# Crosswalk Error

Tags: android, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

Packaging fails with error

```
ERROR: Error: Command failed: /home/name/Android/Sdk/tools/android list target

  + Logfiles at /tmp/crosswalk-app-tools-com.herokuapp.aedntrxns
/usr/lib/node_modules/crosswalk-app-tools/src/crosswalk-pkg:581
                    throw new Error("Packaging failed");
                    ^

Error: Packaging failed
```

This is likely because the file /home/matt/Android/Sdk/tools/android consists of the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo The "android" command is no longer available.
echo For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
echo For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
exit 1
```

how do I direct crosswalk to the appropriate executable for the list target command?

Answer (score 1):

The SDK Tools 25.3.0 release [removed](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html) the deprecated `android` command. Additionally, [Crosswalk is officially dead](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html), so it won't get more updates to use the new tools. A workaround may be to downgrade SDK tools to an older version.

**Update:** SDK Tools 26.0.0 [added](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html) compatibility with legacy commands again. Just update your SDK Tools to make it work again.

Comment: followed your recommendations, and all worked out , thanks!